# react.js image is not getting loaded

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs, background-image

i am trying to put the background image of the div but nothing works for me.
I am quite new to react.js

There is no error in the console also.(Path is correct)

My code like like this.
I am using jsx file format

```
     render() {

    var divStyle = {
        backgroundImage: "url('desktop_wallpaper_by_maria_shanina.png')"
    }

     return (

        <div className="background" style={divStyle} >

            <div id="loginpanel">
                <br/>
      </div>
       </div>
      )
```

Mycode is like this. no error.. but there is no image on screen also.

What should i do?  Thanks

Comment: Inspect the element and see in the styles if it has the background image style loaded correctly. It could probably be a height/width issue.

Comment: I haven't included any height and width.. if i have to do that.. how i can do that

Comment: depends on what you need to accomplish, but try to add to `divStyle` 200px height & width for instance and take it from there.

Comment: its still not working man... size of the image quite big, so i think thats not issue

Comment: Check if the path of your image is correct, react builds and deploy assets and files in a build path, like "/build", have you looked throught this to check if the path is correct, it could be something like, '../assets/desktop_wallpaper_by_maria_shanina.png"? If you're using something to build the project, like webpack, are you sure you have the correct loader?

Comment: yes path is correct man... i am using this webpack https://github.com/srn/react-webpack-boilerplate

Comment: i just hope that it must be correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://codepen.io/jmsherry/pen/mEYRLW?editors=0010

It does work. Can you see that style turning up in your css inspector?

```
var mountNode = document.getElementById('app');
console.log(mountNode, React, ReactDOM);

var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var styles = {
      border: "1px solid",
      color: "#fff",
      height: "200px",
      backgroundImage: "url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg)"
    };
    return (
      <div style={styles}>Seconds Elapsed:</div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<HelloMessage name="John" />, mountNode);
```